# Notepad++, replace two first lines

Tags: replace, notepad++, line

I need to replace some things. This is how the row looks like:

```
44;3lyl
44;3lyl
44;3lyl
44;3lyl
44;3lyl
```

This is how the row should look like:

```
33;3lyl
33;3lyl
33;3lyl
33;3lyl
33;3lyl
```

I want to replace the first two numbers of each line. Please help me with this.

Comment: ctrl-H, select "regular expression."  Find `\d\d(.*)` Replace `33$1`  http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: The site messed it up, this is how it looks like:

http://imgur.com/mYZwcGd    to     http://imgur.com/uZWj1bP

Comment: Still.  Regex.  That's what it's *for*.

Answer (score 3):

Press Ctrl+H ,then in find \d+(;.*)  and in replace 33$1

Make sure Regex mode is on:

[image]

Comment: You have to make sure that Notepadd++ is in Regex search mode, instead of normal or extended.

Comment: The RegEx mode is on, it says it found nothing.

Comment: @Ineedyourhelp if the replace does not work you could provide a screenshot like the one in the answer, showing the file and the replace dialog. Then it may be easier to debug your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use regular expressions you can still achieve what you want using mouse and keyboard and the [column mode edting](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html) function of Notepad++.

You start with:

[image]

Now you can select the first two columns of characters with the mouse keeping the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on you keyboard pressed while dragging your mouse to select the area you need to replace (the first two columns).

Now your selection should look like this:

[image]

Finally you can type the new text, in your case: "33". Notepad++ will overwrite 44 with 33 in all the selected rows:

[image]

Comment: @Ineedyourhelp I'm glad to hear that! By the way if the answer helped you, please remeber to [mark it as "accepted"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)